# How to enable remote connection in SQL Anywhere 17(windows)

Tags: windows, sql, sybase

I downloaded the trial version of SQL Anywhere 17. After the other databases, the interface does not seem very clear. I want to allow remote connection to this server. It seems strange that in tcp / ip listeners I can only select localhost ... How to set up a remote connection?
[List of available tcp/ip listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXDoO.png)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure a listener to enable a remote connection to a SQL Anywhere server. ("remote" = connect to database from another machine?)

**But**: there are two programs coming with SQL Anywhere to start databases. One is *dbsrv17.exe* and the other is *dbeng17.exe*.

*dbsrv* is the network server, *dbeng* the personal server. The network server allows connections from other machines, the personal server does not (because it's meant for developers).

The trial (or "developer edition") typically starts the demo databases with the personal server (because you typically install the server on your developer machine).

You should try to start the demo database with the network server and the try a connection from another machine. Should work (I just tested it).